# Why Netlogon send dns query ipv6

Tags: windows, azure-active-directory

I use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-admx-netlogon#admx-netlogon-netlogon-addresslookuponpingbehavior
set parametr addresslookuponpingbehavior to 2.
When I debug netlogon Nltest /DBFlag:2080FFFF I see in log

```
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteFromAddressLookup: site lookup requested for CZC52220NH (CZC52220NH.domain.name) with lookup policy=0x2.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: querying IPV4=FALSE, IPV6=TRUE on CZC52220NH.domain.name.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: result: 0x251d from DnsQuery_W(DNS_TYPE_AAAA) on CZC52220NH.domain.name
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: total of 0x0(0) DNS records found.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: returning 0x0.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteFromAddressLookup: result: 0x0 for CZC52220NH
04/13 22:11:25 [2036] RS: NO_CLIENT_SITE: CZC52220NH 11.0.3.243
```

Why ipv6 ? Help me set ipv4

Comment: Hello @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT. Thank you for help, but I have no result

Comment: would suggest you to please go through this link and do the things as said in it. It might be of great help.

Comment: Hello @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, i checked what was in the links, but without success

Comment: Can you please disable the IPv6 setting on the AD DNS server and the VPN/Firewall device to be sure that this doesn't happen henceforth and then without fail, do restart the servers/firewalls also for the changes to take effect. Thanks.

Comment: IPv6 was disabled three months ago. Servers/VPN/Firewall have been rebooted more than once

Answer (score 0):

•   You are receiving this error because the **‘IP address lookup behaviour for DC locator ping’** is searching for IPv6 address on priority than the IPv4 adresses. Thus, you will have to ***disable the 'IPv6 (Internet Protocol version 6)'*** in the client system whose IP address DC tries to locate and lookup for in the DNS according to the *configured option ‘2’*. Once the IPv6 is disabled, then try enforcing the group policy once again by executing the command **‘gpupdate /force’** on the client system and *restart the system*, then try again.

To disable the IPv4 on a client system, follow the steps below according to in the screenshot: -

[image: Disabling IPv6]

•   Once done, then please check the **‘Active Directory Sites and Subnets’** management option in the Domain Controller and check whether the IP address range for the client system is defined in for the appropriate site of the Active Directory in that option. In AD Sites and Subnets console, the locations are added where **ADC (Additional Domain Controller)** is deployed and replication is happening amongst the DCs, also the subnets that include the domain joint client systems in those locations respectively are added and configured to the correct site so that when DNS records are synced and replicated on all the DCs and DNS servers, the correct IP address of the client is looked up.

To configure the AD Sites and Subnets correctly, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/ras/multisite/configure/step-2-configure-the-multisite-infrastructure

•   Also, you can disable serving and looking up IPv6 addresses by referring to the details given in the below article and configuring the same on your DNS server: -

https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036617333-How-do-I-disable-IPv6-for-Windows-Server-DNS-

For configuring the policy to make use of IPv4 addresses only in the domain environment, kindly refer to the below documentation link that states the details to configure a group policy for this purpose: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows

Comment: I forgot to say that ipv6 is disabled by the DisabledComponents parameter:0xFF. This policy applies to all domain computers and controllers

Comment: On DNS Servers Listen only ipv4, because DisabledComponents parameter:0xFF i think

Comment: Also I tried the policy for DC DisabledComponents parameter:0x20

Comment: Kindly check whether the AD Sites and subnets have been correctly configured because any client system will look for its nearest AD site for DNS resolution and IP lookup.

Comment: I'm trying to do:
the client has an ip address that is recorded in dns, and which is related to the site. But the client connects via vpn and DC sees it at a virtual ip address that does not belong to any site. Using addresslookuponpingbehavior, I just wanted the client to get to the site by DNS, and not by a virtual address

Comment: I checked everything and tried everything you wrote on the test domain. The result is the same, netlogon uses ipv6

Comment: Kindly check the IPv6 address settings on the VPN side whether the correct VPN client address pool is configured or not and the defined address pool is IPv4 or not. Also, ensure that the IP client address pool correctly configured in the DHCP server in the domain environment such that when a lookup is done for the IP address, it can be found.

Comment: VPN do not use dhcp. This is a software product that does not use dhcp or dns. DNS does not know anything about vpn subnet and should not know. In DNS, there is a registration of the correct ip of the client, both in the forward and in the reverse zone. But netlogon logs show that it is looking for ipv6, although it is turned off everywhere. What else can I see, please tell me. Thanks